# How can I programmatically generate a file at build-time in Create React App?

Tags: create-react-app

I'd like for my Create React App to generate a file called `VERSION.txt` that will end up in my deployed site's `public` directory as part of its build.

I know I can just create a static file in my repo's `public/VERSION.txt`, but I want its contents to come from an environment variable. The ENV variable is REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF, which is coming from my Netlify setup. I'd like my CRA to put this variable in `public/VERSION.txt` (so my React app can easily check it to see if a new version exists), but [the docs on environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) says they're only available in `index.html` (as well as in any source JS code via `process.env`).

As a workaround for now I've put it in a `meta` tag in my `public/index.html`

```html
<meta name="app-version" content="%REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF%" />
```

but my app code now has to parse this string and I'd rather just have a `public/VERSION.txt` to achieve this.

Is it possible for CRA to programmatically generate files at build-time?

Comment: Hey sam, big fan of your work. What did you decide to go with here?

Comment: @TransmissionsDev thank you! I can't remember but I think it wasn't possible with CRA out of the box. Today I would probably be using Next or Gatsby and use one of their ssr hooks to accomplish this.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much for the response. I went with making a small CLI and running that prestart and prebuild. Again, love your videos and MirageJS!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the kind words! <3

Comment: Is there any update on this without using Next or Gatsby?